# Using Interface as parameter in list

Tags: java, object, interface

My question is rather simple. Im trying to make a builder for building charts. The chart data will be filled by an object depending on what program my fellow programmers create Therefore ive used an interface called `ObjectInterface` to make sure that there are certain methods the an object always have.

My question is if i want to add these objects (that i do not know of which type) to an ArrayList is it possible to add them such as this:

```
ArrayList<ObjectInterface> data = new ArrayList<ObjectInterface>();
ObjectType Test = new ObjectType("Test");
data.add(test);
```

in this example the ObjectType is an object that implements the `ObjectInterface`

is this legal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example is perfectly fine.

Furthermore, I think it's pretty good design. One further refinement suggested by @duffymo is to use `List` on the left-hand side:

```
List<ObjectInterface> data = new ArrayList<ObjectInterface>();
```

This way `data` is declared in terms of the abstract list interface, and not in terms of a concrete list implementation.

Comment: I'd prefer List<ObjectInterface> on the LHS, but that's me.

Answer (score 3):

If `ObjectType` is a subtype (or implementation) of `ObjectInterface` then it is legal. Don't you have a Java compiler? it will answer all your "is this legal" type of questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is legal. You can add subtypes of `ObjectInterface`, e.g., `ObjectType`, to `ArrayList<ObjectInterface>`.